# pd get dummies value encoding struggling with column growth

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the below dataset, which I am trying to encode:

In the end, I just want 7 columns (bread, wine, eggs, meat, cheese....), with a 1 or 0 in it, depending on whether that item was purchased.

I have tried pd.get_dummies, but it creates columns item1_bread; item2_bread... and so I cannot complete my analysis. I want to be able to have simply a 1 or 0 value in the column to say whether bread was purchased in that transaction

Can anyone help me please?

```
item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7
Bread,Wine,Eggs,Meat,Cheese,Pencil,Diaper
Bread,Cheese,,Diaper,,,Pencil
Cheese,Meat,Eggs,Milk,Wine,,
Cheese,Meat,Eggs,Milk,Wine,,
Meat,Pencil,Wine,,,,
Eggs,Bread,Wine,Pencil,Milk,Diaper,Bagel
```

My desired output is like:

```
Bread, Wine, Eggs, Meat, Cheese, Pencil, Daiper
1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1,0,0,0,1,1,1
```

Comment: Could you please bring an expected output sample?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have added that now

Comment: can you add second row aswell?

Comment: Sure! I have done that, to mirror what the actual first 2 rows should show. I can only think of doing this with a case statement, but if you had 1000 products that would make this difficult